# How to lowercase an entire Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, lowercase

I'm' trying to build a function to the job because my data frames are in a list. This is the function that I am working on:

```
def lower(x):
        
        '''
        
        This function lowercase the entire Data Frame.
        
        '''
        
        for x in clean_lst:
            for x.columns in x:
                x.columns['i'].map(lambda i: i.lower())
```

It's not working like that!

This is the list of data frames:

```
clean_lst = [pop_movies, trash_movies]
```

I am planing to access the list like this:

```
lower = [pd.DataFrame(lower(x)) for x in clean_list] 
pop_movies = lower[0] 
trash_movies = lower[1]
```

HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` functions from pandas package which works on df / series.

`clean_lst = [i.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()) for i in clean_lst]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a vectorized method for every column in the dataframe

```
x["column_i"].str.lower()
```